# Выборка из mysql по дате

Tags: php, mysql

Есть 2 переменных которых получаем из формы называются они `$start_date` и `$end_date`. Есть запрос к базе

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a.buy_price,
       b.qty,
       b.price,
       b.date
FROM products AS a,
     sales AS b
WHERE a.id = b.product_id
```

Нужно к этому запросу добавить код чтоб он выбирал между указанными датами в форме т е между датами `$start_date` и `$end_date` ...

Пытаюсь делать так

```
SELECT a.id,
       a.name,
       a.buy_price,
       b.qty,
       b.price,
       b.date
FROM products AS a,
     sales AS b
WHERE a.id = b.product_id
      AND date BETWEEN $start_date AND $end_date
```

Выдает ошибку

> Column 'date' in where clause is ambiguous

Подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: нужно, видимо, написать `b.date` или `a.date` - в зависимости где эта дата лежит. А то синонимы для таблиц написали, а `date` непонятно к чему относится..... плюс с таким запросом `$start_date` и `$enf_date` надо будет заключить в кавычки скорее всего... а еще лучше использовать подготовленные выражения.. ну это уже на будущее

Comment: точно ! спасибо а я там писал sales.date и тоже получал ошибку. Ваш ответ верен. Но теперь другая ошибка , почему то он не выводит ничего хотя в таблице есть записи которые лежат между этими датами

Comment: проблема скорее всего в `$start_date AND $end_date` - как я описал выше.

Comment: возможно типы дат не совпадают (`datetime` != `date`, например)

Comment: Благодарю Вас за помощь , Алексей ! да дело было в них одинарные кавычки и помогли.

Comment: Anatol, Вам так же огромное спасибо за поправку и за ответ. Но дело было именно в кавычках оказывается.